# SQL Query issue: Cannot get desired output

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

**Given relational schema:**

Emp(e_name, street, city)

Works_for(e_name, company_name, salary)

Company(company_name, city)

Manages(e_name, manager_name)

**Query: Find the company with maximum no of employees.**

**My try:**

```
SELECT company_name, max(count(e_name))
FROM Works_for
GROUP BY company_name
```

^This gives an error: Not a single group-group function.
What is the right query for this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you need the *table* maximum you can use `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT company_name, COUNT(e_name) AS cnt
FROM Works_for
GROUP BY company_name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

*Update*

Without using `LIMIT` it's not so pleasant:

```
SELECT MAX(company_name)
FROM
(
    SELECT company_name AS company_name
    FROM Works_for
    GROUP BY company_name
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (
        SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM
        (
            SELECT COUNT(e_name) AS cnt
            FROM Works_for
            GROUP BY company_name
        ) T1
    )
) T2
```

Comment: hmm.. i hadnt even thought about order by limit.. This will probably work! thanks! but since we havnt studuied about 'LIMIT', is there any way of doing this without the use of orderby LIMIT?

Comment: yea ur right. its not pretty at all. but thanks man! ill use both as my answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT company_name, count(e_name) count 
FROM Works_for 
GROUP BY company_name 
ORDER BY count desc
```

Then just grab the top one

Answer (score 1):

To try and avoid limit, you could use a having clause:

```
SELECT company_name, count(e_name)
FROM Works_for
GROUP BY company_name
HAVING count(e_name) = (
  SELECT max( count(e_name) )
  FROM Works_for
  GROUP BY company_name );
```

But really limit is a simpler option!

Comment: Is `MAX(COUNT(e_name))` valid SQL?

Comment: Certainly in Oracle; I tried it in Oracle as LIMIT doesn't work in Oracle.  I mainly program SQL into back-end applications, so I don't bother so much naming result columns so I'm fairly sure this sort of pattern works in most databases I've tried.